# Android SDK won't start after initializing

Tags: android, sdk

I installed ADT and SDK in eclipse, and everything works fine, but my SDK manager won't start after initializing. Nothing happens. Here's a screenshot. Any idea? http://prntscr.com/w9u80

In console: [SDK Manager] 'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Comment: tried to run `android` directly from your sdk folder? And you mean `ADT` and not `AVD`, right?

Comment: @WarrenFaith Sry, yes ADT. Whe I run SDK directly from folder, black CMD window just blink once, and nothing happens.

Comment: The error message seems to be well known. Here [my google search results](http://goo.gl/cUWj7) with some good looking answers (even on SO).

Answer (score 0):

Click on this [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) and you will find the SDK plus Eclipse for Android Programming. It is better and faster than previous version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this:

1. Go to your bundels/sdk/tools.
2. Type this command `android sdk`

for more follow this url http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html.

Answer (score 0):

You must run eclipse as administrator,just click right button/ run as administrator. Its a permission issue. I have test it on W8.1 and last version of eclipse "luna".